# How do I access data from a Computed Observables using a click event?

Tags: knockout.js

How do I populate or load data into a table or list using `foreach binding` and click event? I need to pass a value from the click event and bind using foreach.

Currently, on page load I am able to use a foreach with a Computed Observable to populate a table or list. E.g. `ul`.

*Example:*

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*Then:*

```
    self.people = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(observableArrayDataSource(), function (data) {
            return data.personId === personIdFromClick;
        });

      });
```

I need to use a click like below:

```
    self.getPersonIdOnClick = function(person){
       // pass person.personId to the function above. 
      //  Each time a person name is clicked 
      // The redo foreach binding
    };
```

*UPDATE:* [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3dryd04/1/) here with working solution as answered below:

Comment: From a business requirement point of view what is the final outcome here, Is it going to be two lists of people (one for all and the other for filtered where users would click on all people and they drop off from the filtered)? I am just confused as to what exactly you are envisioning ...

Comment: Yes, I am attempting to put up a jsfiddle: So there is a list of persons initially binded with `name` and `Id`. Clicking on the name will then do a foreach and bind detail to a table.  In a nutshell, you click an item and bind all of the details using for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to have an observable in your view model that stores the currently selected `personId`. You don't explicitly "pass" arguments into computeds. By referencing `self.selectedPersonId` inside of the computed a dependency is created. A computed will automatically reevaluate whenever any of it's dependencies change.

```
this.selectedPersonId = ko.observable(null);
this.getPersonIdOnClick = function (person) {
    self.selectedPersonId(person.personId);
};

this.people = ko.computed(function () {
    return observableArrayDataSource().filter(function (person) {
        return person.personId === self.selectedPersonId();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed: I have added a JSFiddle to the question using your solution, in case someone else needs it.